# How to set my own KeyGenerator instance in appsettings.json?

Tags: json, azure-table-storage, serilog, asp.net-core-2.0

I already asked that question [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-azuretablestorage/issues/39) but I feel like Stackoverflow might be faster. This is how I'm trying to do it in my json configuration file:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.AzureTableStorage" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "AzureTableStorage",
        "Args": {
          "storageTableName": "Logs",
          "connectionString": "*************",
          "keyGenerator": "MyApp.Serilog.AzureTableStorage.MyKeyGenerator"
        }
      }
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Verbose"
  }
}
```

This is my generator implementation:

```
public class MyKeyGenerator : IKeyGenerator
{
    public string GeneratePartitionKey(LogEvent logEvent)
    {
        return Environment.MachineName;
    }

    public string GenerateRowKey(LogEvent logEvent, string suffix = null)
    {
        return SUID.nextId().ToString();
    }
}
```

Obviously, the `.ReadFrom.Configuration` operation throws an `InvalidCastException`, since it tries to fit the string content into an `IKeyGenerator` parameter.

How should I set the `keyGenerator` parameter to ensure an instance of `MyKeyGenerator` class is created and given to that parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cloned [serilog-settings-configuration](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration) and after digging into the code, I found how they expect the JSON setting value when the actual parameter is an interface (See [StringArgumentValue.cs](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/blob/552d1669b156dfd38fa9696e18648f257d4d6226/src/Serilog.Settings.Configuration/Settings/Configuration/StringArgumentValue.cs#L59), line 57 to 74).

The correct way to reference the type you want to pass as parameter is to give the **full class and assembly names separated by a comma**. That class **must have a public default constructor** as well.

Ex:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.AzureTableStorage" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "AzureTableStorage",
        "Args": {
          "storageTableName": "Logs",
          "connectionString": "*************",
          "keyGenerator": "MyApp.Serilog.AzureTableStorage.MyKeyGenerator, MyApp"
        }
      }
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Verbose"
  }
}
```

That way, the configurator can instanciate the class properly!

Comment: IMHO it would be much more helpful to not have that `throwOnError: false` argument and let the exception bubble up with the proper error message (type cannot be found). I don't see what use case not throwing on error serves here.